# Optimization problem in a social network

Tags: optimization

I would appreciate anybody's help with a problem I am trying to solve.

- A little background:

given is a social network consisting of people represented as a directed graph, with edge from person A to person B if person A is a follower of pers B on that network. For any set S of people, we say that S reaches all people who are followers of at least one person in S. Everyone is a follower of themselves so any set of people S reaches at least itself

- Problem:

The **optimization** version of this problem is as follows: given a social network and
a parameter k, compute the maximum possible number of people that can be directly reached
by up to k (observers).

The **search** version of the problem is to compute a set of up to k observers, which reaches the
maximum number of people.

**Show** that given a hypothetical algorithm for the decision version of the problem, both the
optimization and search versions of the problems can be solved with at most a polynomial
overhead (i.e., if the algorithm for the decision version takes O(T(n)) time on instances of size n then the optimization and search versions can be solved in O(T(n)c) time for some constant c).

Comment: Please credit the source of all copied material in the question.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/124513/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/124505/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/124497/755

Answer (score 1):

The optimization version can be solved with logarithmic overhead by binary searching on the range $[0,\dots, n]$ of the possible values of $k$, where $n$ is the number of nodes of the input graph.

The search version of the problem can be solved with a polynomial overhead by first solving the optimization problem to obtain the maximum number $m$ of people than can be reached by $k$ observers and then:

- guessing an observer $v$ in the input graph $G$,
- computing the set $R$ of vertices than can be reached by $v$, and
- checking whether $k-1$ observers are enough to reach $m-|R|$ people: if this is the case, then the problem is equivalent to the one of selecting $k-1$ observers in $G-R$, and the whole procedure can be repeated. Otherwise, try with a different vertex $v$.

Solving an instance of your problem when $k=0$ is trivial.

At most $n$ attempts are necessary to guess the right vertex, and the whole procedure is repeated most $k$ times, i.e., the decision problem needs to be solved at most $O(\log n + nk) = O(nk)$ times.